# Why is the USER = N/A and what does event 4689 means?

Tags: windows

Why user = n/a? what is 4689? and why I only get the logoff event but not logon event?

```
Log Name:      Security
Source:        Microsoft-Windows-Security-Auditing
Event ID:      4689
Task Category: Process Termination
Level:         Information
Keywords:      Audit Success
User:          N/A
Computer:      computer name
Description:   A process has exited
```

Thank You

Comment: Have you checked out the M$ site?

Comment: M$? I tried to google, I only know what is event ID 4689 is about = process termination. But I still not sure why user = n/a, it could be because of microsoft standard but I hope to get the actual reason and how to solve it